# Sort groups of rows by partial text

Tags: excel, sorting, grouping

My database outputs data as HTML sorted in a way that is not useful to me. I would like to be able to re-sort it in Excel.  The problem is twofold:

1) The data is output into 9 rows at a time, with 3 header rows.  Each of these 9 rows need to be kept together, in order, when sorting.

2) The primary sort key is the SECOND HALF of one of the data cells.  In the attached image, H14 is the location I need to sort by, containing "3M (WSW)"-- but I don't want to sort by "3M", I want to sort by "(WSW)".  Now, not every data element HAS the portion in parenthesis, and not every data element has anything BEFORE the parenthesis, but the portion inside the parenthesis is all I want to sort by.  The secondary sort key would be the first half of the same cell, and the tertiary sort key would be the part number in A5, A14, etc.

[image: Link to Image of Spreadsheet]

I've searched google and this site for help, and I understand that I can add some additional columns to sort by (or make a VBA program to sort with, but I haven't coded in VBA for something like 15 years now and I don't feel up to it).  This database dump has hundred and hundreds of records, so I need some formulas to use to make these sorting columns-- there's no way I can do this by hand every week with hundreds of records.  I have no idea how to make formulas that will sort by my primary, secondary, and tertiary sort criteria AND keep the rows within the groups in their original order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several days trying, I've come to the conclusion that this task simply cannot be done without VBA.  As such, I brushed up on my VBA (it wasn't as hard as I thought it might be), and wrote the following code.

I summary, I had to parse out the initials, parse the brand name, grab the part number, grab an index, and mash them together into a single string that could be sorted.  Then I'd pull out the index and use that to copy the data elements over to sheet2 and beautify them a bit.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim iElements       As Long
    Dim vSortKey()      As Variant
    Dim iSortOrder()    As Long

    iElements = 0

    ' How Many Part Numbers Were Added?
    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(5 + (iElements * 9), 8)) = True
        iElements = iElements + 1
    Loop
    iElements = iElements - 1

    ReDim vSortKey(iElements)
    ReDim iSortOrder(iElements)

'*************************
' Create the Sorting Key.
'*************************
'   Our Primary Sort is the Initials of the Product Development employee, found in the Parenthesis of Cell H5, and every 9 cells after that
'   Our Secondary Sort is the Brand Name, found before the Parenthesis of Cell H5, and every 9 cells after that
'   Our Tertiary Sort is the Part Number, found in Cell A5, and every 9 cells after that
' Finally, place the location of the element at the end, so we can find it again on the source sheet.
' Each Key (and the source location) is placed in a single string, and seperated by a colon.
'   The Split() command can be used to extract each of these elements from the string, effectively making this a 4D array (index 0 to 3)
'   (but a 4D array that's MUCH easier to sort)
    For i = 0 To iElements
        vSortKey(i) = FindName(Cells((5 + (i * 9)), 8)) & ":" & FindBrand(Cells((5 + (i * 9)), 8)) & ":" & Cells((5 + (i * 9)), 1) & ":" & i
    Next i

    QuickSort vSortKey, 0, iElements

    ' For convenience, extract the "location" of the sorted elements into a seperate array: iSortOrder()
    Dim tmp() As String
    For i = 0 To iElements
        tmp = Split(vSortKey(i), ":")
        iSortOrder(i) = CLng(tmp(3))
    Next i

'*****************************************
' Create the Finished Worksheet on Sheet2
'*****************************************
' Finished Sheet must have a repeating header, borders between elements, and other beautification done
' Note that there are 37 rows to a page, and with 7 rows to an element, 5 will fit per page with 3 rows left for the header.
    Dim pagecount As Long
    pagecount = 0

    For i = 0 To iElements

    ' Every five elements is a new page.  Every new page, copy the header and update current page count.
        If (((i + 1) Mod 5) - 1) = 0 Then
            CopyHeader ((pagecount * 37) + 1)
            pagecount = pagecount + 1
        End If

        For m = 1 To 16
            If (((i + 1) Mod 5) - 1) <> 0 Then
                Sheet2.Cells((pagecount * 2) + (i * 7), m).Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                Sheet2.Cells((pagecount * 2) + (i * 7), m).Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThin
            End If

            For n = 0 To 7
                Sheet2.Cells((pagecount * 2) + (i * 7) + n, m) = Sheet1.Cells((5 + (iSortOrder(i) * 9) + n), m)

                If ((n = 0) Or (n = 2)) Then
                    Sheet2.Cells((pagecount * 2) + (i * 7) + n, 11).NumberFormat = "$#.#0"
                ElseIf ((n = 1) Or (n = 3)) Then
                    Sheet2.Cells((pagecount * 2) + (i * 7) + n, 11).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
                End If

            Next n
        Next m

        Sheet2.Cells((pagecount * 2) + (i * 7), 1).RowHeight = 22.5

    Next i

End Sub

Public Sub CopyHeader(iStart As Long)

    For i = 1 To 16
            Sheet2.Cells(iStart, i) = Sheet1.Cells(1, i)
            Sheet2.Cells(iStart, i).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            Sheet2.Cells(iStart, i).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
            Sheet2.Cells(iStart, i).Font.Bold = True
    Next i

End Sub

Public Function FindName(vStr As Variant) As Variant

    Dim StartPos As Long
    Dim EndPos As Long
    Dim Length As Long

    FindName = ""

    If Len(vStr) > 0 Then
        StartPos = InStr(vStr, "(") + 1
        EndPos = InStr(vStr, ")")
        Length = EndPos - StartPos

        If Length <> 0 Then
            FindName = Mid(vStr, StartPos, EndPos - StartPos)
        End If
    End If

End Function

Public Function FindBrand(vStr As Variant) As Variant

    Dim Length As Long

    FindBrand = ""

    If Len(vStr) > 0 Then
        Length = InStr(vStr, "(") - 2
        If Length > 0 Then
            FindBrand = Left(vStr, Length)
        Else
            FindBrand = vStr
        End If
    End If

End Function

Public Sub QuickSort(vArray As Variant, inLow As Long, inHi As Long)

  Dim pivot   As Variant
  Dim tmpSwap As Variant
  Dim tmpLow  As Long
  Dim tmpHi   As Long

  tmpLow = inLow
  tmpHi = inHi

  pivot = vArray((inLow + inHi) \ 2)

  While (tmpLow <= tmpHi)

     While (vArray(tmpLow) < pivot And tmpLow < inHi)
        tmpLow = tmpLow + 1
     Wend

     While (pivot < vArray(tmpHi) And tmpHi > inLow)
        tmpHi = tmpHi - 1
     Wend

     If (tmpLow <= tmpHi) Then
        tmpSwap = vArray(tmpLow)
        vArray(tmpLow) = vArray(tmpHi)
        vArray(tmpHi) = tmpSwap
        tmpLow = tmpLow + 1
        tmpHi = tmpHi - 1
     End If

  Wend

  If (inLow < tmpHi) Then QuickSort vArray, inLow, tmpHi
  If (tmpLow < inHi) Then QuickSort vArray, tmpLow, inHi

End Sub
```